# Fastest way to get nanos unix epoch time in Java

Tags: java, time, timestamp, unix-timestamp, epoch

I currently do this to successfully get the current epoch time in nanos:

```
Instant inst = Instant.now();
long time = inst.getEpochSecond();
time *= 1000000000l;
time += inst.getNano();
```

However, it's a bit too slow for my use case, taking around `1us` each call after the JVM has warmed up.

Is there a faster way to do it?

I'm happy with a solution that gives me the microseconds since epoch, as long as it's faster than the above.

Comment: Most computer hardware can't measure time in nano seconds.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I'm happy with a solution that gives me the microseconds instead of nanoseconds.

Comment: You'd probably need to dip into native code for a high performance timer. The `Instant` approach is bound to be slow and results may vary. What are you using these values for?

Comment: Did you try with System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: @MohinuddinLuhar I need micros resolution

Comment: @Kayaman I'm using them inside my trading system to drive decision making, logging, etc. If I can save `0.2us` on the calculation I'd be very happy.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250112/fastest-way-to-measure-elapsed-time-in-java) for some related information. You might be better off combining `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()` if you can. They're intrinsics, so they should give you a noticeable performance boost.

Comment: Can you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351565/system-currenttimemillis-vs-system-nanotime

Comment: @Kayaman `Instant.now()` is internally doing exactly that, i.e. combining `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `System.nanoTime()`. The only thing you'd gain by trying to do it yourself, is eliminate the need to create an `Instant` object.

Comment: @Andreas indeed, that was my point, not to mention going through the `Clock` class. Although whether bypassing that is faster than the JIT optimized version remains to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

What may work is to run:

```
long n1 = System.nanoTime();
long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
long n2 = System.nanoTime();
```

a number of times until the difference between n1 and n2 is less than the resolution you want (it's about 400 ns on my PC after a couple of iterations).

You can then use the difference between `n1` (or n2 or an average of the 2...) and `m * 1e6` as an offset that you need to add to `System.nanoTime()` to get the current epoch nanos.

Disclaimer:

- `System.nanoTime` doc explicitly states that the resolution is at least that of `System.currentTimeMillis()`, which may be > 1 ms. So no guarantee that you will get microsecond resolution.
- Corollary: this probably doesn't work in all environments (you may never get n2-n1 small enough - or it may be 0 just because the resolution of your system is too low).
- `System.nanoTime()` may be out of sync over long periods - so this is a trade off between precision and performance.
- You also need to account for possible arithmetic overflow.

See also: [Current time in microseconds in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712205/current-time-in-microseconds-in-java)